# How to setup SDL2/SDL.h in visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdl, sdl-2

I tried to setup SDL 2 in visual studio following similar instruction to [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQzAHcojEKg) and the result was that visual studio was recognizing SDL.h but it was not recognizing SDL2/SDL.h and the include folder of sld2 development tools [(link)](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) does not have any SDL2/SDL.h file. How to setup SDL2/SDL.h in visual studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `SDL2` in `SDL2/SDL.h` is a folder.It is a folder that keeps SDL.h in the directory the compiler looks #include directives in.Change that include folder name to SDL2.

Comment: Hi. I hope you don't mind my commenting here re a post of mine you just proposed an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32209481) to. I have edited the post to clarify it, including re using definitions properly & re defining "violating FD" for a NF.